# Python is outputting json with string quotes

Tags: python, json

I have a model that I'm trying to convert into a json so I can better see how the data is changing (it's very deeply nested and hard to get a feel of even with a debugger).

Code looks something like:

```
derived_game = GameUnderstanding().derive_gamestates(game=game)
        derived_outfile = derived_game.json()

        with open('derived_game.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(derived_outfile, outfile)
```

However, it's outputting with these string quotes, which I think is interfering with my tools that can organized json in a readable way.

```
"{\"roster\": {\"home\": {\"coaches\": [], \"players\": []}, \"away\": {\"coaches\": [], \"players\": []}, \"officials\": []}, \"current_gamestate\":
```

Is there some way I should be exporting to a json that would retain better formatting?

Comment: If that's the content of your file, it seems `derived_outfile` is already a JSON string, and not a Python dictionary.  If that is the case, `outfile.write(derived_outfile)` should work.

Comment: worked! Thank you. If you'd like to submit that as an official response I'll accept it.

Comment: the var derived_outfile already contains json and you are applying json.dump again on a json. that's why the output is looking like this. you can either remove json() from "derived_game.json()" or directly write to file without json.dump method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's the content of your file, then `derived_outfile` is already a JSON string, and not a Python dictionary. If that is the case, then this should work:

```py
with open('derived_game.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(derived_outfile)
```